# Moving Service with API to private subnet in Amazon VPC

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-vpc, private-subnet

Our API was public. We'd access it from `api.domain.com`.

The service has moved to a private subnet with an Amazon VPC.  The web app is hosted on a public instance which communicates via API to the private instance.  How do we create an endpoint to access the API hosted on the private instance?

I believe we can access it via `XXX.XX.XXX.XXX` which is the private IP address of the instance. However, we'd prefer to access it with a named endpoint such as `api.domain.com`.  How can we do this?

Is this as easy as editing the /etc/hosts file on the public instance?
`XXX.XX.XXX.XXX api.domain.com`
I worry about the scalability / reliability of this method.

Comment: Are both instances in the same VPC?

Comment: Yes.  Same VPC - web app in public subnet, api service in private subnet

Comment: The API service will only be accessed by the web app - never exposed to the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [Private Hosted Zone](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html) in Route53 to resolve DNS names within your VPC.

Comment: The public web app - should it have an A record in both public & private hosted zones?  www.domain.com resolving to the same public IP?

Comment: You shouldn't need to duplicate anything like that from your public zone. You should only need to create a new record for it in your private zone if you want to use the internal IP to hit it from within the VPC.